# How do I pass around parameters through a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using

> Rails Version: 4.2.0
>
> OS:            Windows 7

I have 3 Active record models. (User, Post, and Comment) with

**User**

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
```

**Post**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many   :comments
```

**Comment**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

Now if I (a logged in user) wanted to create a comment from a post's show page. How would I go about passing the id of the post to the comment's create action?

The only way I can think of would be something like this:

Post's Show page

```
link_to 'Create comment', new_comment_path(post_id: @post.id)
```

Comment's new page (Inside the form)

```
hidden_field_tag ':post_id', params[:post_id]
```

Comment's create action

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
@comment.post_id = params[':post_id']
```

This feels sloppy, is this the right way or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested resources:

```
resources :posts
  resources :comments
end
```

Your link would go to `new_post_comment_path(@post)`

Inside your CommentsController, you will have access to `params[:post_id]` from the path to create your comment.

Another option is to use a form object (non ActiveRecord backed model) , but that sounds like overkill for your use case.